# AngularJS Scope.on and scope.emit calling order in a filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In one of my filters, a value which is changed in another controller,  is watched. Based on the updated value, I want to decide whether the emit should be called or not. It is as following.

```
scope.$on('XChanged', function(event, x) {
              console.error( '==order list has changed : ' + x  );
              console.warn('INSIDE FILTER ON '+event);

             scope.bx = true; // bx variable is initialized in the controller where the filter is called and default is false.
            });
          console.warn('AFTER FILTER ON 1 >>'+ scope.bx);

           if( !scope.bx  ){
             scope.$emit('handleEmit', {msg: 'RECYCLE' });
             console.error( scope.bx+ ' Recycle requested. ');
           }
```

But the problem is, scope.on is executed firstly and execution doesn't happen from the top to bottom in the filter. Also, even though bx is set to true in the scope.on, `if( !scope.bx  )` becomes true, that means the assigned true value to bx is not sett... Might be I m going wrong way... can you let me know how can I come up with this. What all I want to do is, based on the value changed in the scope.on, the emit should be executed. (in other words, bx boolean value is changed in the scope.on and the bx's updated value should be able to decide, whether emit should be executed or not.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use a $watch.

```
    scope.$on('XChanged', function(event, x) {
         console.error( '==order list has changed : ' + x  );
         console.warn('INSIDE FILTER ON '+event);

         scope.bx = true; // bx variable is initialized in the controller where the filter is called and default is false.
        });
         console.warn('AFTER FILTER ON 1 >>'+ scope.bx);

    scope.$watch('bx', function(newVal, oldVal){
        if (newVal == oldVal)
            return; //shit happens ;-)

         if( !scope.bx  ){
           scope.$emit('handleEmit', {msg: 'RECYCLE' });
           console.error( scope.bx+ ' Recycle requested. ');
         }

    });
```

Comment: Thanks for attention and the answer. But thing is,  if( !scope.bx  ){ } part should be out of the scope.on. Because, scope.$on('XChanged' may or may not be called. But scope.$emit should be invoked based on the scope.bx value.

Comment: that means that you're into an infinite loop : the function inside the "$watch" must probably change the value of $scope.bx, and then beeing called with no stop. duplicating the code inside ``if (!scope.bx)`` cannot be done?

Comment: @Débora : sending the event inside the function called by the "$on", and keeping it outside for your purpose.